# Could not connect to Postgres from Symfony 4 + Docker

Tags: postgresql, symfony, docker

I run into the strange problem. I've created docker-compose file to build php + nginx + postgres services:

```
version: '2'
services:
    db:
        image: orchardup/postgresql
        ports:
            - "5433:5432"
        environment:
            LC_ALL: C.UTF-8
            POSTGRESQL_USER: postgres
            POSTGRESQL_DB:   db
            POSTGRESQL_PASS: postgres

    php:
        build: .docker/php-fpm
        ports:
            - "9002:9002"
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/symfony:cached
            - ./var/log/symfony:/var/www/symfony/var/log:cached
        links:
            - db

    nginx:
        build: .docker/nginx
        ports:
            - "8001:80"
        links:
            - php
        volumes_from:
            - php
        volumes:
            - ./var/log/nginx/:/var/log/nginx:cached
```

After that I created DB schema by running **bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force** . The tables and migrations created just fine. Seems like DB connection is ok. I checked this by connecting to db from my machine through psql with credentials from **.env**, the tables are there.

But when I go to the web page and trying to authorize, I get an error told me the connection is not ok:

```
Connection refused Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5433?"
```

I checked in both case I have dev environment - from the web page and from the console. I tried 5433 and 5432 ports with no success. I tried everything I could find for 3 hours.

This is the output from the postgres container:

```
# netstat -tlpn | grep 5432
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      12/postgres

# grep listen /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
listen_addresses = '*'     # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way for containers to talk to each other is through IPs. By linking multiple containers together through `--link` (or `links` in `docker-compose`), docker creates a secure tunnel between those two containers so that we don't need to expose any ports externally.

If you try to connect to your database from your local environment through a database client, you will be able to connect to it from `127.0.0.1:5433` as the port is exposed to your host through the docker-compose file. This is the reason why your schema update command succeeded.

> Docker exposes connectivity information for the source container to
>   the recipient container in two ways:
>
> 1. Environment variables,
> 2. Updating the /etc/hosts file.
>
> Ref: https://docs.docker.com/network/links/#communication-across-links

In order to connect to your database (which is running in the `db` container) from the `php` container, you will need to get the host of your `db` container through the environment variable `DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR` (I might be wrong on this, but type `env` in your `php` container's terminal to verify. You will need to SSH into your `php` container).

Alternatively, you can use the second method, which is just `db` as the hostname instead of `127.0.0.1` since docker updated the `/etc/hosts` file in the `php` container to map your linked container's name to its IP, and in this case, the value mapped to the hostname `db` is the same as the value stored in the environment variable `DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR`.

Comment: Thank you !!! I googled that inject env variables into container is deprecated for now. I used your second method and it works =) But seems like now I should switch connections manually when I running some console command and when I running web app. For web app now I have: DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/mydb?sslmode=disable

Comment: Yes, I think there are two ways to solve this: (1) SSH into your web container and run those console commands there. That way, you'll only be using the `DATABASE_URL` with `db` as the hostname, or (2) Whenever you run commands in your local environment, you can set your environment variable to your local one before you run those commands, say `DATABASE_URL=local_url && my_custom_command`.